# OCC module ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, dll

I'm importing OCC module but it shows error "DLL load failed". The code I tried is:

```python
from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import *
```

The error it showing :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

~\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\OCC\Core\Aspect.py in <module>

     16 # Import the low-level C/C++ module
     17 if __package__ or "." in __name__:
---> 18     from . import _Aspect

     19 else:
     20     import _Aspect

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm working in Jupyter notebook

Comment: same here, installing openocc by conda

Comment: Same issue with conda install of 7.4.1